# Suggestion: reduce number of points required to cast a close vote

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, down-votes

Here's an example of a not-so-good question: *[Domain and sub domain in different hosting providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51767186/domain-and-sub-domain-in-different-hosting-providers)*

It's about system management, so it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. Googling for the question title brings up a bunch of responses, and the top response is a tutorial from the [AWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) side, so clearly the OP (who has been on Stack Overflow for 4+ years) hasn't indicated that any research. On the other hand, it is clearly written and is answerable by a person who knows the [GoDaddy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoDaddy) side.

As of this morning it's been viewed 13 times, downvoted twice, and has no close votes or explanatory comments. This doesn't seem very useful: it doesn't help the OP in any way, and doesn't leave a good question to help the next user.

If close votes are to be useful, it seems that they must be less "expensive" in relationship to downvotes. One approach would be to dramatically lower the number of rep points required: from 3,000 to, say, 500. That would still limit close votes to people who had been on the site long enough to have a vested interest.

Another possibility is that when a user of sufficient rep clicks the downvote button, s/he is asked if a close vote would be more appropriate.

Or, as a completely different alternative, accept that closed questions aren't adding anything to the site and eliminate closure altogether.

---

Before asking this question I tried [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=meta.stackoverflow.com%20reduce%20points%20needed%20to%20close%20questions&oq=meta.stackoverflow.com%20reduce%20points%20needed%20to%20close%20questions) and [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=meta.stackoverflow.com%20make%20it%20easier%20to%20close%20questions%20than%20to%20downvote%20them&oq=meta.stackoverflow.com%20make%20it%20easier%20to%20close%20questions%20than%20to%20downvote%20them). The closest I found to a duplicate was
 *[More effective closing / downvoting of junk questions to help with the signal-noise ratio?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252561)*.

Comment: Note that users with 15 or more rep can flag a post, and put it in the close votes review queue. Then >3K users can cast their votes. The difference between actually casting a vote and doing that is just one close vote (the queue is unfortunately very full, though).

Comment: How many high-rep users spend their time reviewing close votes? I've done it a couple of times, but it's certainly not the first thing that I think of when I go to the site. That's why I'm suggesting lowering the initial friction (or removing the need).

Comment: @kdgregory not enough, that is for sure, given the size of the CVQ being at 10K.

Comment: You're on place [3620](https://heather-eggnog.glitch.me/?page=1&userid=42126) (with 79 reviews) of the 7879 users that I know of that have reviewed at least once in the CVQ on SO.

Comment: @rene - do you have any way of finding out how many people with < 3k rep flag questions for closure?

Comment: @kdgregory no, not really. The [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) doesn't have review data and in [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) the tables related to reviews and flags are anonymized. Only SE staff can query that info on their internal SEDE instance

Comment: On puzzling, when the rare occasion of a review queue needing reviewing happens, it is reviewed within the first minute :P

Answer (score 4):

> One approach would be to dramatically lower the number of rep points required: from 3,000 to, say, 500. That would still limit close votes to people who had been on the site long enough to have a vested interest.

The downside of lowering this privilege (so much) is that it will be available to people who are lucky to place their first and only answer on a Hot Network Question. I do not expect those users to be able to determine what is on-topic and off-topic for Stack Overflow. In fact, the question you mentioned is an excellent example of why we **shouldn't** do this; that user has 538 reputation and apparently doesn't know such a question is off-topic.

> Another possibility is that when a user of sufficient rep clicks the downvote button, s/he is asked if a close vote would be more appropriate.

Well, downvotes and close votes serve different purposes. Downvotes are for questions which are low quality and/or lack proper research; close votes are for questions that don't belong on the site at all. Of course, some questions deserve both, but they're by no means one-on-one.

Comment: To add to your point: the max amount of rep you can earn by just editing is 1K, to prevent users from gaining certain privileges just by editing. Setting the limit at 500 would allow users that have never posted anything this privilege.

Comment: Re "Downvotes are for questions which are low quality and/or lack proper research," we also have close options that seem to cover those cases: either "unclear what you're asking" or "debugging help needs an example". Perhaps the reasons for closure should be scaled back to off-topic or duplicate?